# Switching Themes drops focus for activity on Android 6

Tags: android, android-theme

Has anyone ever experienced a scenario where you use the AppCompatDelegate to change the theme, then if you hit the back button to go to a previous activity, that activity can not be interacted with.  I see the following errors when I tap

```
Dropping event due to no window focus: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_MOVE, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=245.0, y[0]=928.9525, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=2, eventTime=80728630, downTime=80727874, deviceId=15, source=0x1002 }
```

Any time I try to interact with the screen I get this. If I switch apps, turn the screen off/on, or anything that would cause it to get focus again it's fine.

My exact scenario is that I have an Activity I'm using. I decide to change theme so I go into a settings menu and change them. I then hit back to get out of the settings to my original activity.  After I change the theme I can interact in the settings activity.  It's only once I leave settings with the back button that I lose the ability to interact.

NOTE: Modern Android 10 devices do not have this issue, only my older Android 6.0.1 devices do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a new version of `appcompat` available that should solve your issue, `1.2.0-beta01`. It looks like in version `alpha03` they solved this issue:

> Fix issue where stopped Activities were not resuming on API Level 23 and below ([I45201](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/971248))

You can find more details on the [appcompat releases page](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/appcompat).

Update your `build.gradle` file to have the following library reference and you should be good to go:

`implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0-beta01'`